# Transparent XUL Window in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, window, transparency, xul, translucency

I've created a Firefox extension which opens a new window and this window is transparent, means it doesn't have a background - the desktop behind it shines through!

It was done with `<window style="background:transparent !important; -moz-appearance:none !important;">`.

While it works perfectly in Firefox 3.x, I can't get any transparency in Firefox 4. The background is white. Is there any way to achieve this transparency effect in Firefox 4?

(PS: It worked on Windows only. If, after fixing it for Windows, anyone has an idea how to make it for other OSes, I would be more than happy.)

Comment: Those styles work for me in Firefox 4, and should suffice for all platforms. However translucency (as opposed to transparency) only works on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Neil, can you give me some details on what you did, e.g. what is the full XUL, how you opened the window etc.? Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: Actually I cheated and used DOM Inspector to add that attribute to another window (I think it might have been the Preferences window) although note that in that case the window only becomes transparent if you open a menulist or other popup (i.e. the style isn't completely dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

did you include the global skin in your xul page? (`<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>`)
Your description is typical of this skin not being imported (and I think it became required in recent firefox builds).